# Issue with downloading videos with PyTube

Tags: python, pytube

I know that there are a few posts on this very same topic, but all of those posts are a bit old and none of them worked for me.  So please, I have tried everything, upgraded Pytube, upgrading pip, switched to other versions of Pytube and Pip, reinstalled both.  But nothing, even at the script level I have tried typing the url manually, and I have tried passing the url through the script.  Many people have tried to help me on many different platforms as well!  But, to no avail, NOTHING, and I mean NOTHING has worked.  Basically the issue, the script gets up to the Video Download section, but it never downloads no matter how long I wait, even shorter videos, it says that the file can not be played (because of Pytube not fully getting the video).  Someone please help me.

```
from pytube import YouTube
import time

print("The Youtube Video Downloader")
time.sleep(0.2)
print("\nBy:   ViridianTelamon.")
time.sleep(0.2)
#url = input("\nInput The Full Url For The Youtube Video That You Want To Download (Shortened Urls Will Not Work):  ")
url = input("\nInput The Url For The Video:  ")

#print(f"Url Inputted:  {url}")

#print(url)

video = YouTube(url)

time.sleep(0.2)

print("\n----------Video Title----------")
time.sleep(0.2)
print(video.title)
time.sleep(0.2)
print("\n----------Video Thumbnail Url----------")
time.sleep(0.2)
print(video.thumbnail_url)
time.sleep(2)
print("\n----------Video Download----------")

time.sleep(0.2)

video = video.streams.get_highest_resolution

video.download()

print("\nVideo Successful Downloaded In The Same Directory As This Script.")
```

Comment: There are a ton of Youtube downloaders out there, have you tried any others?

Comment: I realise this, but I wanted to make my own.  That's the only reason I even did research into it, it's because I wanted to make one myself.

Comment: What's the question? How do you know it's not working? Edit the question. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Following up on Peter Wood's comment, what *specifically* is the issue? Is anything printing? If so, what? You need to tell us what "not working" means.

Comment: try y2mate.com...

Comment: Thank you Muhammad for the suggestion, but I want to make a Youtube Video Downloader not use one (to test my skills).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
video = video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
```

You forgot the `()` For function

Comment: This doesn't address the original problem at all.

Comment: So write the code correctly

Comment: I fixed this part, so thank you for that.  But the video stills does not download no matter what.  The video file exists, but no matter how long I wait it just can not be played.